# prompt interrupts my capistrano script during cloning repository

Tags: ssh, mercurial, capistrano, bitbucket

I use capistrano for deployment, bitbucket for hosting my mercurial repository the deploy.rb script works fine but the problem is that the first time I clone from bitbucket it throws this exception with yes/no continue thing which of course screws the automation process.

This is what happens:

```
running ssh hg@bitbucket.org "hg -R vireton-dev/forecasts serve --stdio"
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (207.223.240.181)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I am using these lines in my script:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :scm_verbose, true
```

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I get rid of that prompt?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you have not yet accepted the RSA fingerprint for the host. If you ssh into the server as your deployment user and run

```
ssh hg@bitbucket.org
```

it should prompt you to accept the RSA fingerprint. Once you do, the server will save the fingerprint in the .ssh/known_hosts file and not prompt again in the future. This will allow your future deployments to succeed. The SSH connection to bitbucket from the code above will fail, but it will resolve the issue, as we don't need to be able to log into the remote host to accept the RSA key.

Comment: i don't want to log on the server to fix that. to fix that i upoad known hosts that trusts bitbucket to the server and the automated process goes without prompting but it feels like a hack is there a different way?